# How to escape apostrophe inside an input made with apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql, string, apostrophe

I have a profile page in which I want to display informations from the database for most users, and a form with the current data as default value for the users with modification rights.

```
if ($IDprofile == $_SESSION['userID'])
{
    echo "<form method='post'>
            Surname: <input type='text' required name='surname' maxlength=50 
                value=".htmlentities($user['Surname'])."><br>
            Name: <input type='text' required name='name' maxlength=50 
                value=".htmlentities($user['Name'])."><br>

        Birthdate (format YYYY-MM-DD): <input type='text' required name='BirthDate' value='";
        if ($user['BirthDate'] != null)
            echo $user['BirthDate'];
        else
            echo "-";
        echo "'><br>

        Description: <input type='text' maxlength=255 name='description'                                 value='";
        if ($user['Description'] != null)
            echo htmlentities($user['Description']);
        else
            echo "-";
        echo "'><br>
        <input type='submit' value='OK'></form>";
}
```

As you can see, I tried with `htmlentities`, which should transform the apostrophe into `&#39;`, but it doesn't work. Other methods like `addslashes` and `addcslashes` don't work either.

What is displayed is my form input with the value it should have, until the place where there should be an apostrophe, where it just ends. `addslashes` does the same, with a `/` before the end.

What puzzles me the most is that I have a surname with an apostrophe in it in my database, and this one is displayed just fine.

Comment: Can you give example users that do display correctly and those that don't? Can you post an example of how it should look like and what it's doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`htmlentities` by default only encodes `"` double quotes, because those are the more common terminators for HTML attributes. If you want it to encode `'` single quotes too, you need to set the `ENT_QUOTES` flag:

```
htmlentities($foo, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401)
```

(`ENT_HTML401` is the other default flag; these days you may want to use `ENT_HTML5` instead.)

You should also actually delimit your attributes with quotes! Currently your result looks like `value=James`, which isn't incorrect, but will get you into trouble once your values contain spaces or, well, quotes or other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Please try outputting your variables like this:

`htmlspecialchars($user['Surname'], ENT_QUOTES);`

Also be sure to [disable magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in your system so you don't get any extra slashes automagically when posting new data.